# What is the meaning of "in the realm of"?

Tags: phrases

There is an expression "*in the realm of ...*".

What does it mean exactly, and in what cases it is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[realm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/realm)

> 1. A community or territory over which a sovereign rules; a kingdom.
> 2. A field, sphere, or province: the realm of science.

Knowing this, the phrase *in the realm of* is pretty straightforward. Although I should mention, that it is often used in metaphorical sense, as in *in the realm of dreams*, meaning *in the area, where the dreams rule*.

Answer (score 1):

This reference [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/realm) defines *realm* to mean...

> 1.
>   a royal domain; kingdom: the realm of England.
>   2.
>   the region, sphere, or domain within which anything occurs, prevails, or dominates: the realm of dreams.
>   3.
>   the special province or field of something or someone: the realm of physics; facts within the realm of political scientists.

so *in the realm of* would mean "in the kingdom of (some monarch)", "in the region of" or "in the field of".

I've also heard it used to mean "approximately" as *in the realm of £1,000*, but I don't think that's quite right.

Comment: Like you, I feel that *in the realm of [some value]* isn't quite right. Clearly arrived at via your own paraphrasing *"in the region of [some context]"*, but I just can't put my finger on exactly why it seems like a stretch too far.

Answer (score 0):

The way I hear this word most often is for exaggeration, especially when used in the negative.  So I might say that an object is not even in the realm of $1000 or that something is not even in the realm of possibility.  The reason this works with exaggeration is that realm conveys a large area.  It also sounds so definite.